# EF Core increasing memory usage in insert loop

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-core, bulkinsert

I have a long running application that downloads some data and inserts them in bulks in a sql server database.
I have disabled tracking and set `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false`

```
        _context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        _context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        while ((data = getData()) != null)
        {
            await _context.MyTable.AddRangeAsync(data);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

This code starts inserting data fast, but after a few hours I can see long pauses and the memory used grows (many GB). I suspect EF core keeps in memory a copy of the data.

**Is there any way to disable this behavior?**

I replaced with this raw sql code where multi-items are inserted in a single command and the memory is not increasing at all.

```
        while ((data = getData()) != null)
        {
            string cmd = $"INSERT INTO dbo.Table(name1,name2) VALUES "
                       + string.Join(",", data.Select(x => $"('{x.name1}', '{x.name2}')"));
            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(cmd);
        }
```

I would like to use the non-raw version, but am I missing something regarding the memory?

Comment: EF Contexts keeps every entity added to the context, so the memory allocated by the context gets bigger. In bulk insert scenarios, the recommendation is to work in batches, disposing and recreating the context. Also, you can use some third party bulk insert nuget package. They internally use, usually, plain SQL to do the inserts, but work great and to you it will be transparent.

Comment: @Pepelui360 thanks, I would expect to be some setting 'not to keep every entity added to the context'.

Comment: I had that problem too before I switched to Linq2db. Linq2db is faster and better memory management than EFCore.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you generate the context ->

either use scope or "using" for the request, so you garbage collect the EF-Core instance after each insert. That should fix your memory "leak".

```
using(_context = new context())
{
   await _context.MyTable.AddRangeAsync(data);
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

or if you are using DI: use the IServiceFactory interface,

```
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
   var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
   await context.MyTable.AddRangeAsync(data);
   await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```